# Substring the first occurrence of each part of a string in another string in c#

Tags: c#, substring

I have these two strings:

1. `"Project.Repositories.Methods"`
2. `"Project.Repositories.DataSets.Project.Repositories.Entity"`

I want to *trim* the first occurrence (from the first index in `2`) of parts of string 1 in string 2, so the desired result would be:

`"DataSets.Project.Repositories.Entity"`

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Do both strings always start with the same thing? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your string 1 doesn't occur in your string 2... I think you mean you want to trim the part that is contained in string 1...

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed No not always, I tried tokenizing the first part (splitting by '.') i'll add the code i wrote when it works. i'm aiming for the best practice

Comment: @ZoharPeled   Yes i want to trim parts of str1 in 2

Comment: @AliKleit In your question, you are supposed to include code that _doesn't_ work. If you managed to get it to work, that's an answer then.

Comment: @AliKleit _No not always_ Does that mean you want to remove `b.c` from `a.b.c.d`?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed No just the first parts, i'll edit my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear what do you mean by "best way"; if you want to `Split` each string by `.` and get rid of *common chunks*, i.e.

```
  Project        Project       - these chunks should be 
  Repositories   Repositories  - removed (they are same in both strings)
  Methods        DataSets
                 Project
                 Repositories
                 Entity
```

you can try using *Linq* e.g.

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string prefix = "Project.Repositories.Methods";
  string source = "Project.Repositories.DataSets.Project.Repositories.Entity";

  string[] prefixes = prefix.Split('.');

  string result = string.Join(".", source
    .Split('.')                                            // split into 
    .Select((value, index) => new { value, index})         // chunks  
    .SkipWhile(item => item.index < prefixes.Length &&     // skip
                       prefixes[item.index] == item.value) // common chunks
    .Select(item => item.value));

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  DataSets.Project.Repositories.Entity
```

**Edit:** No Linq solution, inspired by **urbanSoft's** answer:

```
  string prefix = "Project.Repositories.Methods";
  string source = "Project.Repositories.DataSets.Project.Repositories.Entity";

  // We have 2 cases when all starting characters are equal:
  string result = prefix.Length >= source.Length 
    ? ""
    : source.Substring(source.IndexOf('.', prefix.Length) + 1);

  for (int i = 0, dotPosition = -1; i < Math.Min(prefix.Length, source.Length); ++i) {
    if (prefix[i] != source[i]) {
      result = source.Substring(dotPosition + 1);

      break;
    }
    else if (prefix[i] == '.')
      dotPosition = i;
  }

  Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! nice explanation

Answer (score 0):

> No just the first parts

If only the first parts do matter why not simply iterate until the first character mismatch?

*Updated my answer to take @Dmitry Bychenko comments into account.*

```
string a = "Project.Repositories.Data";
string b = "Project.Repositories.DataSets.Project.Repositories.Entity";
int dotIdx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    if (a[i] != b[i])
        break;
    else
        dotIdx = a[i] == '.' ? (i+1) : dotIdx;
Console.WriteLine(b.Substring(dotIdx));
```

Comment: It will throw an exception 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' in the case the second string matches the first partially (str2 = "P")